# How does ClojureScript differentiate its namespaces from Clojure namespaces?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, clojurescript

I'm working through *Web Development with Clojure* and I noticed that the ClojureScript examples the author provides use the conventional `app-name.core` namespace, which is also being used by the Clojure part of the application for a lot of boilerplate code from Luminus.

ClojureScript and Clojure are often used to evaluate the same code for client and server sides of an app, respectively, so how does it differentiate between code in the ClojureScript core namespace and the Clojure core namespace? Does it use the directory structure? Can you use code from both w/o having to specify?

Comment: depends on your build tool. The convention is to use `.cljc` files for code that is shared between clj and cljs. There's no convention I'm aware of that deals with naming namespaces. You probably want different ones

Answer (score 0):

You program in JavaScript regardless of whether your code runs on Node.js or in a browser. Obviously depending on the platform, the API isn't the same.

My understanding is that ClojureScript is just a compiler. You write in plain Clojure (with a subset of the API) and then use ClojureScript to compile Clojure to JavaScript.

Therefore I don't think there's any difference in how namespaces are managed:

- Replace `.` with `/`
- Append `clj` or `cljs`
- Replace `-` with `_`
- Unless configured otherwise assume that `src` is the root directory

So `app-name.core` "resolves" to `src/app_name/core.cljs` for example.

I *think* (could be wrong) that on the JVM if a file doesn't exist on the disk, the compiler will look inside JARs (if any). Obviously that wouldn't happen with ClojureScript.

Answer (score 0):

I have said in other answers that IMHO it is a mistake to include both frontend code (CLJS) and backend code (CLJ) in the same git repository.  You fundamentally have two different programs that are running independently, are on separate hardware, and are communicating over a network. Any common utils used by both programs should be in a separate utility library, which would be a 3rd repo.

This organization provides the most independence and clarity for the 2 (or 3) codebases, independent of the language in use.  It applies equally to any combination of languages used by the 2 programs:

- Python & Python
- Python & Java
- JS (browser) & Python
- CLJS (browser) & Java
- CLJS (browser) & Clojure
- any other combination...

So you use `*.clj` files for the backend code, and `*.cljs` files for the frontend code [1].  If you have any common utilities, make a 3rd repo and use `*.cljc` files for this shared library.

For frontend CLJS code, it is much easier IMHO to use the new `figwheel-main` and Clojure Deps tooling than the older lein tooling.  Please see [figwheel.org](https://figwheel.org) for details.  This also makes it easier to keep the CLJ repl and the CLJS repl separate (no "piggieback" stuff required).  It also keeps the CLJ compilation and CLJS compilation separate, which also simplifies things.

---

Having stated the above, I hope the answer to your original question becomes clearer.  The CLJS code may have a namespace `demo.core`, that is compiled into JavaScript, that is running in a browser, on the user's computer.  The CLJ code may also have a namespace `demo.core`, that is compiled into Java bytecode, that is running on a backend server in the cloud.  So there is only one ns `demo.core` in each execution environment, so they never clash.

So, we see that the 2 compilers treat the CLJ and CLJS codebases as independent programs. This is why it is simpler IMHO to use two different git repositories to prevent conflating the two independent codebases.

---

Footnotes:

[1]. If you have macros in the CLJS frontend code, you will also need to define them in either `*.clj` or `*.cljc` files due to quirks in the CLJS compiler. We will ignore that complication here.

Comment: I would say it is much more of a naming problem. All templates are pretty bad at this. There is absolutely no good reason to have a `.core` namespace to begin with. Moving them to separate git repos doesn't make that any better. There are still two different meanings for one name. Just use better names like `demo.server` and `demo.frontend` or better yet follow the JVM naming conventions and use `my.company.frontend` and `my.company.server`.

Comment: I agree that the convention of having a `*.core` namespace isn't always a good fit.  However, it can serve a purpose to denote the central or "core" ns, where the other namespaces are more specialized and serve a supporting role to the core. It's somewhat analogous to Java's `main(String[] args)` method - it gives the reader information on where to start.

Comment: Maybe, but my argument was that it would then be `demo.frontend.core` and `demo.server.core`. There should never be namespaces with the same name that serve completely different roles. It is fine for `.cljc` and macro namespaces that actually have the same purpose.